# when using EPPlus in C#, how to export a globally clear date format?

Tags: c#, epplus, date-formatting

I am using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which is an excellent Excel wrapper to use from C#.  I am using it in an asp.net-mvc site and I ran into one strange issue.  I want to export a cell with a date format that will work for everyone globally.  My web server is in London but i have users all around the world.

What is the correct way to format the Numberformat so the date shows up as something like "12-Apr-2016" (so there is no confusion what is the day and what is the month)

```
_currentWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = myDate;
_currentWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MMM-yyy";
```

but it doesn't seem to export correctly.

What is the right syntax for formatting dates that show up in excel globally and could not be confused?

Comment: What's wrong with setting the value of the cell as the date in the string format you want?

Comment: What does "globally clear date format" mean? Do you mean "locale-independent"? Only the ISO8601 format does that ie `yyyy-MM-dd`. No names, just numbers, year at the front. The stored date doesn't have any format, it's a binary OA Date.

Comment: What are you seeing in excel?  It seems to work for me.  I am using the default US culture in excel so maybe your settings are affecting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the correct **user** locale, which should make things "*globally clear*" for them:

```
_currentWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Style.Numberformat.Format =
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
```

[System.Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.aspx) was made for cases like this.